# Is there a way to get all the open http connections on a host in go?

Tags: go, go-http

I have a go webserver. Is there a way where I can get all the open http connections on that host?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a type to record open connections in response to server [connection state](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.ConnState) changes:

```
type ConnectionWatcher struct {
    // mu protects remaining fields
    mu sync.Mutex

    // open connections are keys in the map
    m  map[net.Conn]struct{}
}

// OnStateChange records open connections in response to connection
// state changes. Set net/http Server.ConnState to this method
// as value.
func (cw *ConnectionWatcher) OnStateChange(conn net.Conn, state http.ConnState) {
    switch state {
    case http.StateNew:
        cw.mu.Lock()
        if cw.m == nil {
            cw.m = make(map[net.Conn]struct{})
        }
        cw.m[conn] = struct{}{}
        cw.mu.Unlock()
    case http.StateHijacked, http.StateClosed:
        cw.mu.Lock()
        delete(cw.m, conn)
        cw.mu.Unlock()
    }
}

// Connections returns the open connections at the time
// the call. 
func (cw *ConnectionWatcher) Connections() []net.Conn {
    var result []net.Conn
    cw.mu.Lock()
    for conn := range cw.m {
        result = append(result, conn)
    }
    cw.mu.Unlock()
    return result
}
```

Configure the net.Server to use the [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values):

```
var cw ConnectionWatcher
s := &http.Server{
   ConnState: cw.OnStateChange
}
```

Start the server using [ListenAndServe](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.ListenAndServe), [Serve](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.Serve) or the TLS variants of these methods.

Depending on what the application is doing, you may want to lock ConnectionWatcher.mu while examining the connections.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qR4Cm4tDCb5).